# HTML5 & CSS3 responsive website design margin issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin, padding

Please take a look [**here**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mxztpwpe), on my code. I am trying to make a responsive web page, but there is weird margin from top and bottom of first article column. I am talking about margin between top navigation and content column and between footer and content column, and I just set 10px margin to right column like below.

```
.content {
width: 69%;
float: left;
margin:0;
padding:0 10px 0 0;
```

}

I am new to web designing, and I don't know what wrong I am doing here. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
.topcontent{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) take a look on http://cssdeck.com/labs/mxztpwpe again, that's all I wanted.

Comment: You should also upvote Jeff's answer. His is the more accurate and also resolves the problem.  The whitespace was due to <h2> top-margin and bottom-margin of last <p>.  Mine is just a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You're experiencing the way margins collapse together.  Set the `top-margin` on the `H2` tag to 0, and the `bottom-margin` on the last paragraph to 0.  Then to restore the white space, add top and bottom padding to the `article` element.

More info about margin collapse here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing